# Can't use hirb rails gem

Tags: rubygems

[Changes]

- the problem was not the typo of 'enale' instead of 'enable'
- the installation goes without problem with the `--no-ri --no-rdoc` flags
- now the doing `require enable` gives an error instead of `false` (have no idea why)

I am having some trouble using the Gem [hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) for formatting the output of rails console.

```
$ gem install hirb --no-ri --no-rdoc
Successfully installed hirb-0.6.2
1 gem installed

$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> require 'hirb'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- hirb
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

I am running Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3, Bundler 1.1.3, Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: typo: hirb.enaBle with a letter 'b' in it

Comment: simply add --no-ri --no-rdoc for gem install and it won't yield for doc install issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've made a typo, you should type `Hirb.enable`

Add `gem hirb` to Gemfile of your rails project.

Comment: I have updated the question. The problem was not the typo. Please take a look above. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add 'gem hirb' to Gemfile of your rails project?

Comment: I forgot. What a silly mistake to make. It is now working. Thanks.

Comment: is there anyway to automatically run Hirb.enable?

Comment: Try out the .pryrc file, add 'Hirb.enable' to this file. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Adding Hirb to a gloabl `~/.pryrc` will work, but you should probably check `if defined? Hirb` or all your other projects will throw an error .